# Segfault in D for too large inputs

Tags: segmentation-fault, d, phobos

The following D program crashes for input 939971 or higher, but not for input 939970 or lower:

```
#!/usr/bin/rdmd --shebang -w -d-debug --relocation-model=pic
    import std.stdio;
import std.bigint;
import std.conv;
import std.array;
//extern (C) void fibonacci (int* pointer, int length);
int main(string[] args)
{
  args.popFront();
  foreach(size_t i, string a; args) {
    writeln(fibonacci(to!BigInt(a)));
  }
  return 0;
}



BigInt fibonacci (BigInt input)
{
  struct FibMatrix
  {
    BigInt a;
    BigInt b;
    BigInt d;

    this(bool test)
    {
      a = 1;
      if (test) {
        b = 1; d = 0;
      } else {
        b = 0; d = 1;
      }
    }

    void square()
    {
      BigInt f = b^^2;
      b = b*(a + d);
      a = a^^2 + f;
      d = d^^2 + f;
    }

    void opOpAssign(string op, FibMatrix) (FibMatrix input)
    {
      static if (op == "*")
      {
        BigInt temp1 = b * input.b;
        d *= input.d;
        d += temp1;
        b *= input.d;
        b += a*input.b;
        a *= input.a;
        a += temp1;
      } else static assert(0, "Unsupported operator");
    }
  }
  if (input == 0) {
    return BigInt(0);
  } else {
    input -= 1;
  }
  FibMatrix base = FibMatrix(true);
  FibMatrix result = FibMatrix(false);
  version (none)
  {
    writeln (result.a);
    writeln (result.b);
    writeln (result.d);
  }
  if (input % 2 == 1) {
    result *= base;
  }
  version (none)
  {
    writeln (result.a);
    writeln (result.b);
    writeln (result.d);
  }
  input /= 2;
  while (input > 0) {
    base.square();
    if (input % 2 == 1) {
      result *= base;
    }
    input /= 2;
  }
  return result.a;
}
```

Stack trace:

```
#0  0x0000003c51b492e6 in __memcpy_ssse3_back () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x000000000043d6d8 in std.internal.math.biguintcore.inplaceSub() ()
#2  0x000000000043c340 in std.internal.math.biguintcore.mulKaratsuba() ()
#3  0x000000000043c519 in std.internal.math.biguintcore.mulKaratsuba() ()
#4  0x000000000043ad34 in std.internal.math.biguintcore.mulInternal() ()
#5  0x000000000043a7ef in std.internal.math.biguintcore.BigUint.mul() ()
#6  0x000000000040a8a6 in std.bigint.BigInt.__T10opOpAssignVAyaa1_2aTS3std6bigint6BigIntZ.opOpAssign() ()
#7  0x0000000000403f00 in std.bigint.BigInt.__T8opBinaryVAyaa1_2aTS3std6bigint6BigIntZ.opBinary() ()
#8  0x000000000040456b in getints.fibonacci() ()
#9  0x00000000004035d9 in getints.fibonacci() ()
#10 0x0000000000402f4a in D main ()
#11 0x000000000045bfea in rt.dmain2._d_run_main() ()
#12 0x000000000045bc06 in _d_run_main ()
#13 0x0000003c51a21b45 in __libc_start_main () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#14 0x0000000000402d29 in _start ()
```

Looks like a bug in Phobos to me - am I correct?

Comment: see my comments on dejan's answer - I think he's right about the crash itself, but I'm pretty sure too that the actual problem is inside phobos, so yes, most likely a bug in phobos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was a bug in std.BigInt, which caused a crash when multiplying excessively large BigInt values. This may be because of a bad implementation of the Karatsuba multiplication algorithm, since preventing it from being used fixes the problem, forcing it to use the standard way of multiplying BigInts (which is less efficient for such large inputs, but does not have the bug).

Answer (score 1):

I think your application process is reaching the stack size limit. What I am getting here when I compile and run is:

```
object.Error: Access Violation
----------------
0x0041DDDC
----------------
Press any key to continue . . .
```

0x0041DDDC is a familiar number - it is precisely 4MB (4 * 1024 * 1024). So my first guess is - you reached the stack size limit.

UPDATE: little bit of digging what is the default stack size that DMD sets resulted in finding [this thread on D forum](http://forum.dlang.org/thread/ijcbgu%24vnn%241@digitalmars.com). According to the thread, DMD sets 4k kilobytes (4mb) stack size apparently, which I believe explains why we got the error above.

Comment: That doesn't make sense...the documentation for BigInt mentions heap allocation.

Comment: The stack looks messed up to me too.. I recompiled with the phobos modules in debug mode (easier than it sounds: just add the individual modules to your dmd -debug command line) and got this: `core.exception.AssertError@d/dmd2/src/phobos/std/internal/math/biguintcore.d(1783): Bigint Internal Error: Asymmetric Karatsuba` I don't know much of anything about bigint, but my guess is without the debug build, that assert never triggers, and it overwrites the scratch buffer or something, resulting in access violation and/or stack smashing. I guess bottom line, likely a phobos bug

Comment: And commenting out the `if (x.length <= KARATSUBALIMIT)` a few lines above the assert seem to make the problem go away  (I didn't run it to completion, was taking too long, but it didn't crash either.) - it always uses the other multiplication algorithm then. I'm sure something in the karatsuba impl goes out of bounds in this condition, corrupting memory. I have no idea how to fix this, but definitely worthy of a bug report, especially since it is an internal module's assert going off, it surely isn't your code's fault.

Comment: Reported as bug 11599 on D bugzilla.